# How many substrings of "aabbbccdd" can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many substrings of "aabbbccdd" can be formed ?
When I am trying to approach this problem by using the formula

> $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\ +\ 1$$
>   Where n is the number of terms in the string.

I am unable to get the desired answer.
By the way answer given in my book 40.
According to traditional approach whenever substrings have to be calculated then 1+2+3+...till n terms this sum is used (and is very obvious why this is true) but when I applied on this problem then I am unable to get the correct answer.
Although there is a slight difference that here some terms are repeated...so how to calculate in that case..?

Comment: Not sure what that formula means in this context.  Just work recursively, from the starting letter.  How many substrings begin with $d$? Using that, how many begin with $c$?  and so on.  Or, more simply, note that any substring must have the form $a^Ab^Bc^Cd^D$ where $a\in \{0,1,2\}$ and so on.  Note:  I don't get the answer $40$ this way.

Comment: Calculate the numbmer of similar substrings. For example the first letter alone is 'a', and the second letter alone is also 'a'. The book considers these as the same substrings.

Comment: @lulu I thought the same as you. There must be different definitions of "substring" out there. Maybe it means convex subinterval, so to speak.

Comment: @Ned  The only other definition I can think of is the one that distinguishes place value.  So $\{a\}$ is two different substrings according to whether you choose the first or the second $a$.  But in that case the answer would be $2^9$ since a substring would be the same as a subset of the indices.

Comment: @lulu If it means distinguishable convex intervals, then pick two bar locations from 10 -- that's 45, then subtract 6, for duplicates a, b, b, c, d, bb, then add 1 for the empty substring, for  total of 40.

Comment: @Ned  Fair enough.  Certainly not what I mean by "substring".

Comment: Guys substring is not same as subsequence...like If we take "abcdef" then one of its possible substring can be "bcde" but a substring cannot be "bde".. i.e. it has to be adjacent elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the first $a$ by $a_1$, the second by $a_2$ and similarly for the other letters.

We have 9 substrings beginning with $a_1$. We have only 7 beginning with $a_2$ (because the substring $a_2$ is a repeat of the substring $a_1$). Then 7 beginning with $b_1$, 4 beginning with $b_2$ and 4 beginning with $b_3$. Then 4 beginning with $c_1$ and 2 beginning with $c_2$. Finally 2 beginning with $d_1$. Then we have the empty substring.

Total $9+7+7+4+4+4+2+2+1=40$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...actually I was messing around with same strings again and again and that's why was unable to get to 40...your approach seems sensible..